Access token is null when passing credentials from Google to SDK in .NET
.NET 8
I created a bucket in Google cloud storage and uploaded a file manually. I now want to read said file via the SDK using .NET
First, I created OAuth credentials from here
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?hl=en
I downloaded the JSON file and use it in my application by passing it to the GoogleCredential object:
   GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("fullPathToMyFile");

The credentials file looks like this:
  {
      "type": "authorized_user",
      "client_id": "sssssss",
      "project_id": "ffffffstorage",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret": "fffffffff",
      "redirect_uris": [ "http://localhost:5173" ],
      "javascript_origins": [ "https://cfdffffd" ]
    }

When I get to this line of code:
    var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);

    //Download a file from Google Cloud Storage
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await storageClient.DownloadObjectAsync(bucketName, fileName, memoryStream);

I get the following error:
 The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error

I see why I'm getting this. The credentials object is basically null. Below is a screenshot from VS2022

How do I get correct credentials (or an access token) so I can download files from my Google storage bucket?
Thanks

You should use Application Default Credentials which is a mechanism that automatically obtains credentials from your runtime environment. This (usually) avoids having to provide credentials explicitly in code. ADC makes your code simpler, more portable and more secure.

See this example too.
